# What is wrong with my customCardProps code as it is not display filepreview

Tags: list, json-formatting

I have the below code added to my list view, I am trying to show the filepreview on hover over the file name but nothing is showing, can anyone see any code errors please or can they suggest why this will not work :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 135,
  "width": 180,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container ms-bgColor-teal"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "button",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton",
          "role": "presentation"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-teal sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "style": {
          "align-items": "center",
          "padding-top": "10px",
          "background-color": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '','#008080','#3d9970')"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "img",
            "style": {
              "height": "60px",
              "width": "60px",
              "display": "=if([$Image_URL] == '', 'none', '')"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "src": "[$Image_URL]"
            }
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "ms-fontColor-white sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent sp-card-multiline sp-card-keyboard-focusable"
            },
            "style": {
              "height": "80px",
              "text-align": "center",
              "padding-top": "10px",
              "word-break": "keep-all"
            },
            "txtContent": "[$FileLeafRef]",
            "customCardProps": {
             "openOnEvent": "hover",
             "directionalHint": "rightCenter",
             "isBeakVisible": true,
             "formatter": {
              "elmType": "filepreview",
               "attributes": {
                 "src": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '','','thumbnail.large')"
                  }
                }
              }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I have checked the revisions submitted but cannot see what changes were made, cutting and pasting the code into my formatting - still has negative results . I am still unable to see a filepreview ?

Comment: I have noticed @ is missing from thumbnail so have corrected the line to "src": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '','','@thumbnail.large')",  but still not working